# How can I use a Dropbox directory as a virtual host Document Root in OSX?

Tags: macos, apache, apache2, lamp, virtualhost

1. I set up LAMP on my OSX Lion server and everything seems to be working fine when I leave the defaults on.

Either: 
A) Removing the username.conf file from /etc/apache2/users leaves the default running:

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

B) Otherwise, i.e. if i leave username.conf in the destination for localhost goes to the default in username.conf which is:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory "/Users/USERNAME/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

1. I would like to create a virtual host that points to one of my dropbox subdirectories so that I can develop seamlessly across devices.

However, when I try to point to /Users/USERNAME/Dropbox and any subdirectory therein I get  the following errors:

```
[Fri Feb 24 19:00:06 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Users/username
[Fri Feb 24 19:00:35 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Warning: DocumentRoot [/Users/username/Dropbox/MY/DIRECTORY] does not exist
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using My-MacBook-Air.local for ServerName
[Fri Feb 24 19:00:36 2012] [warn] mod_bonjour: Skipping user 'USERNAME' - no valid index file.
[Fri Feb 24 19:00:36 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Feb 24 19:00:36 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Feb 24 19:00:36 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.8 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
```

1. Where and what can I change to allow access?

Comment: Is it just me, or does anyone else think that this sounds like a really dangerous idea, give Dropbox's security record?

Comment: Considering I'm only using it for personal development purposes with no mission critical content I don't think it's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Dropbox.  If you need this kind of functionality, use [WebDAV](http://www.webdav.org/) or host your own [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/) server.

Dropbox has had a [series](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/05/dropbox_securit.html) of security problems (even [recent ones](http://venturebeat.com/2012/04/06/facebook-dropbox-security-hole/)) that make it "scary" for many IT people.  There's even software like [Dropship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropship_%28software%29) that was designed to take advantage of some of its vulnerabilities.  (Dropship doesn't work anymore, but it *did* for an alarmingly long time.)  There has been at least one [complaint to the FTC](http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/threatlevel/2011/05/dropbox-ftc-complaint-final.pdf) about Dropbox making false security claims on their web site.  Respected journalists have [reported on failures](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/sorry-dropbox-i-still-dont-trust-you/4173) with Dropbox's subscription model that indicate the company still hasn't got it together.

Dropbox-the-company aside, you're asking a third party to keep an unencrypted copy of your data.  This may be your source code for a site, log data or temporary files that might contain privileged/sensitive information.  YOU may not be nervous about this, but what about the people who interact with you, whose data you may inadvertently be exposing to a third party (or their security policy) without disclosure?

For a hobby site, perhaps it doesn't matter.  But a hobby site is what trains you for larger projects.  You'd be better off getting in to good habits earlier rather than later.

If you need Dropbox-*style* functionality, [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/) is an open-source workalike that lets YOU provide the shared storage for your files.  There are [others](http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/06/7-good-dropbox-alternatives-for-linux.html).  Put them on your co-located server, access them via SSH.  You can review the source code of SparkleShare's (or any of the other open source optons) so that your safety is in YOUR hands, rather than that of corporation whose priority is their bottom line rather than your safety and security.  (Why does Dropbox spend any money paying developers to fix security holes?  Because it improves their bottom line.  There can be NO other reason, according to US corporate law.  A corporation's sole priority is to maximize shareholder return.)

Comment: I'd have to say this isn't a good answer. I'm in the same position and want to use Dropbox. This is because I sync files between work and home and don't have admin rights on my work machine. Thus using Dropbox to keep things synced helps a ton.

Comment: Okay then, use dropbox, but do so with the awareness that your privacy is not under your control, your data may be leaked without your knowledge, and you set up a dependency on a third party whose business interests and policies may not (probably don't) coincide with your own.  I don't have skin in the game - I really don't care whether people use dropbox.  But people using dropbox should care, and should be aware of the risks.

Comment: People who use Dropbox should not be storing sensitive data on Dropbox. These are development files, personal projects, and contain no personal information.

Comment: Right.  Only people who don't use Dropbox should be storing sensitive data there.

Comment: The question was not whether or not to use Dropbox, it was *how* to use Dropbox in the stated circumstance. A personal recommendation (pro or against this practice) might be appreciated in a closing comment, but should be preceded with a proper answer pertaining to the actual question.

Comment: @hced - Ya, I got that.  Unfortunately, as well-intentioned as my answer was, "the community" keeps paying me back with downvotes even though this answer is from two months ago.

Comment: @Graham - nice update.  While you still didn't answer the question, you've provided a decent rationale for your original answer.  While I don't know if people will remove their downvotes, perhaps this will help you avoid more of them.  :)

Comment: The formalities of Stackoverflow Q&A etiquette aside, I found this "answer" to be bloody informative. Have my +1.